# ClickOnce Application missing System.IO.Compression

Tags: c#, nuget, clickonce, system.io.compression

I have a `ClickOnce` App which references `System.IO.Compression`, the reference being managed by NuGet.

`System.IO.Compression` is (my default) marked with `Copy Local = True`, and indeed it is copied to the bin folder.

However the Publish\Application Files list does not include this DLL (even when I select Show all files)

There is a solution, which is to add the DLL as a content only file to the project. But this seems a little ugly to me, and weird. I am using VS 2017 RC 15.0.26014.0.

Is there something I have done wrong, or am misunderstanding?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx) Section: To mark files as prerequisites

Comment: That requires the dll to be listed under Publish\Application Files, which it is not. (See my original question), Hence the problem!